# WebSharing Enable in mac 10.8

Tags: sharing, osx-mountain-lion, sites, system-preferences

In mac 10.6.8 systempreference->sharing->WebSharing is there but mac 10.8 websharing not in sharing folder how can i add and enable websharing in systempreference panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this on a few Macs running OSX 10.8:

http://amz.clickontyler.com/WebSharing.zip

It creates a PrefPane in System Preferences, with two toggles:
- web on/off
- php disabled/enabled

On one of the Macs it didn't work at first. I uninstalled and re-installed it.
It can be uninstalled by right-clicking on the PrefPane, and selecting “Remove Preference Pane”. Or by removing it from YourUserName/Library/PreferencePanes/ or from /Library/PreferencePanes, depending how you installed it.

On re-install, it worked, but I think it doesn't 'keep track' of the service if for instance, you just kill the httpd process, or stop it through Activity Monitor. I don't think WebSharing PrefPane knows. It has to be re-toggled.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be downloading a ZIP file from an essentially anonymous source. Or, is there something I don't know about 'clickontyler'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure, if it's an good idea to use WebShare PrefPane from ClickOnTylor...

It asks for the user password after toggle, but toggles also if you escape the input of the password. 
Yesterday I switched WebSharing off (checked by Safari localhost). Today I have seen WebSharing PrefPane says still "off". So I removed it from SystemControl. Then I realized, that Safari localhost still answers "It works".

In conclusion: using WebSharing PrefPane without having knowledge on backgrounds is not a good idea, if you know the background I feel you don't need WebSharing PrefPane.